# ExtJS 6. Prevent deferred rendering of comboboxes with local store

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a simple combobox which is instantiated like so:

```
{
    xtype: "combobox",
    emptyText: "Geometry",
    queryMode: "local",
    displayField: "name",
    valueField: "id",
    forceSelection: true,   
    allowBlank: false,  
    itemId: "GeometryType", 
    value: "1",
    store: Ext.create("Ext.data.Store",{
        fields: ["id", "name"],
        data: [
            {"id": "1", "name": "Point"},                                
            {"id": "2", "name": "LineString"},
            {"id": "3", "name": "Circle"},
            {"id": "4", "name": "Box"},
            {"id": "5", "name": "Polygon"}
        ]
    })
}
```

When I expand (or hit the dropdown arrow) this combobox for the first time, I see in the inspector, that in the `DOM` structure of the page appear a number of new items like:

```
<div class="x-boundlist x-boundlist-floating x-layer x-boundlist-default x-border-box" style="width: 388px; right: auto; left: 6px; top: 183.5px; height: auto; z-index: 19000;" id="boundlist-1245" tabindex="-1" data-componentid="boundlist-1245">
<div id="boundlist-1245-listWrap" data-ref="listWrap" class="x-boundlist-list-ct x-unselectable" style="overflow: auto; height: auto;">
<ul id="boundlist-1245-listEl" data-ref="listEl" class="x-list-plain" role="listbox" aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false">
<li role="option" unselectable="on" class="x-boundlist-item x-boundlist-selected" tabindex="-1" data-recordindex="0" data-recordid="10" data-boundview="boundlist-1245" id="ext-element-26">Point</li>
...</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that it takes much more than 250ms to create these items in the `DOM`. So, I, as a user, feel some significant delay and it does not looks good. A simple combo loading for about half of a second! I hope, I can speed up this process with some property (deferred: false or something like that). But I do not know whether such a property exists.

Comment: Your question doesn't add up. When I run this and click the combo it shows the list immediately: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jub

Comment: In my case, when I do it for the first time, I see a significant delay, but when I do it for the second time it shows up immediately. Anyway, if we could force immediate rendering (instead of deferred, like it is now), it would be great.

Comment: Well then you should post a test case that demonstrates what your issue is, since it obviously doesn't occur with the sample code you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `combobox` is a special kind of `pickerfield`. A `pickerfield` has a function `getPicker()` that will try to get the existing picker, and if it doesn't exist, it creates the component of the picker.

ExtJS does the first call to `getPicker()` when someone clicks on the trigger, but that doesn't mean that you couldn't call it earlier if you really wanted to:

```
var combo = Ext.widget({
    ...
});
combo.getPicker();
```

Please note that if you have a form full of comboboxes, and you call getPicker on all of them during creation, the delay would be noticeable during form rendering.